# Azure Pipeline - Post-Deployment Gate for Databricks Job

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-databricks, azure-deployment

**UPDATE:** I am significantly editing this question as comments below highlighted the need for more clarity and detail

Objective is to have a multi-stage pipeline defined in a yaml file. The first stage "Build" has a task which triggers a Databricks job from Azure Pipeline (using databricks cli). This job may take a while to finish. Build Stage should only succeed after job status has been confirmed with "SUCCESS".

One approach would be to add a while loop that checks for job status every X minutes, see code example below (only shows the task of triggering the job and checking the status / example taken from [here](https://github.com/SaschaDittmann/MLOps-Databricks/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml)):

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Train Model'
  jobs:
  - job: Train
    displayName: 'Train Model'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'
    steps:

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Run Training Job'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          run_id1=$(databricks jobs run-now --job-id $(databricks.job.train.id) | jq ".run_id")
          run_state=$(databricks runs get --run-id $run_id1 | jq -r ".state.life_cycle_state")
          while [ $run_state == "RUNNING" -o $run_state == "PENDING" ]
          do
            sleep 30
            run_state=$(databricks runs get --run-id $run_id1 | jq -r ".state.life_cycle_state")
          done
          result_state1=$(databricks runs get --run-id $run_id1 | jq -r ".state.result_state")
          
          if [ $result_state1 == "SUCCESS" ]
          then
            exit 0
          else
            exit 1
          fi
          
- stage: Staging
  displayName: 'Deploy to Staging'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
```

I cannot use the above approach because it blocks the build agent from the available pool of agents for other pipelines in the queue.

Comment below points towards using [post-deployment gate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops) as a potential solution for this problem.

How could this be implemented? yaml code snippet to indicate the solution would aready be very helpful

Comment: This is what post-deployment gates are for. You haven't explained much about the specifics of how you can check the status of the long-running operations, so I suggest you refer to the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Mann, this looks useful indeed. I have defined all stages of my pipeline within a yml template. Is it possible to configure post-deployment gates within yml? Was not able to find this unfortunately

Comment: Yes, at the environment in a deployment job.